erron when using lateral join in Spark. In Athena it works
I get this error:
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:  mismatched input 'my_schema' expecting {')', ','}(line 86, pos 33)
for this code:
SELECT
my_table.id AS id,
my_table.name AS name,
    ...
    '210624100'                                                      AS segment,
    'shard01'                                                        AS shard_name,
    'ndb'                                                     AS database_name
FROM my_schema.my_table LEFT JOIN my_schema.some_table
ON my_schema.my_table.ID = my_schema.some_table.ID
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM my_schema.another_table a_t WHERE a_t.NAME = my_table.NAME
---------------------------------^^^
    AND a_t.ID = my_table.ID AND a_t.IS_ACTIVE IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) active on TRUE
WHERE
    my_schema.my_table.type_id in(2, 8)


I see an extra comma after a_t.NAME = my_table.NAME

Just made a mistake when copied the error, I edited the question.

Did you try running the query in a SQL tool? If so, what happened? It seems OK to me.

@Stefanov.sm OK, it works OK in Athena, but it doesn't work when it runs on Spark on AWS EMR, there I see the error.

A different SQL flavour in Spark maybe?

Perhaps, LIMIT clause in subquery not allowed Spark in AWS.

@ValNik So how else can I return just one row?

It seems that LEFT JOIN LATERAL is not supported in Spark. Try using a scalar subquery instead.

Syntax is like SELECT * FROM t1,  LATERAL (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1); (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-lateral-subquery.html)

If issue is in clause LIMIT 1, you can order subquery rows and take rn=1.
Try
SELECT
my_table.id AS id,
my_table.name AS name,
    ...
    '210624100'                                                      AS segment,
    'shard01'                                                        AS shard_name,
    'ndb'                                                     AS database_name
FROM my_schema.my_table LEFT JOIN my_schema.some_table
     ON my_schema.my_table.ID = my_schema.some_table.ID
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
       SELECT * 
          -- order rows 
         ,row_number()over(partition by a_t.ID order by is_active desc) rn
       FROM my_schema.another_table a_t 
       WHERE a_t.NAME = my_table.NAME
         AND a_t.ID = my_table.ID 
         AND a_t.IS_ACTIVE IS NOT NULL 
   ) active on rn=1  -- take row with rn=1
WHERE my_schema.my_table.type_id in(2, 8)

Order by is_active desc - for example. You can use any the appropriate order.
demo

Still get a similar error in Spark.
